# Can I add custom scripts to Fiddler Everywhere?

Tags: fiddler, fiddler-everywhere

I've just switched to Linux, and so I had to use Fiddler Everywhere. All I see is a "Rule Builder", when I want to insert a custom script. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a menu entry such as Rules > Custom Rules
Is it absent?
If so, maybe it depends on the license you have?

Comment: I can't find it. I'm using a free trial, and my interface looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/E97sUR8.png